# Twilio WhatsApp Autopilot - How to Start The Conversation

Tags: twilio, whatsapp

Is there any way to make the Autopilot start the conversation. What i need is, I have Customer Mobile Numbers and i need to send to them a automated WhatsApp Message. and based on there inputs, Autopilot response to them.

Thanks,

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please see [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for suggestions how to improve your question.

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to initiate a conversation using one of your WhatsApp approved templates using the Twilio Messages resources. Once the user responds (and the 24 hour free form text opens), you can configure the Webhook for WhatsApp to execute your Autopilot assistant.

[Twilio WhatsApp production sender and template creation](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360039246774-Twilio-WhatsApp-production-sender-and-template-creation)

[Twilio API for WhatsApp *(Send an outbound freeform WhatsApp Message)](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/api)

[WhatsApp - Autopilot Channel](https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/channels/whatsapp)

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

Welcome to StackOverflow!

You can initiate a session with the user without the user greeting the bot by connecting the trigger widget's `Rest API` trigger event to either a `make outgoing call` or, in your case, the `send message` widget, as shown below.

[image: flow to initiate SMS]

Then, if the call is answered or the message is sent, you can connect those actions to the `Send to Autopilot` widget, below.

[image: Send to Autopilot widget].

Lastly, under the `config` section of your `Send to Autopilot` widget, put in the Collection task you want to run when the outbound call or message is initiated by your Twilio client and not the user.

[image: Collection]

Let me know if this helps :D

Comment: Hi lizziepika, I don't used Twilio Studio. in using the console. is there any options?

Comment: You do not need to use Studio, this can be done via the Rest API as well. https://www.twilio.com/docs/autopilot/api